# Initialize object with value using operator "=" in C++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have a class with one field. I want to overload the `=` operator so I can assign a string directly to the member `str` of the class. Here is my example but the compiler says `cannot convert from const char[10] to strtype` I would like to ask why is that?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class strtype {
    string str;
public:
    strtype()
    {
        str = "Test";
    }

    strtype(string ss)
    {
        str = ss;
    }

    strtype operator= (strtype &st)
    {
        strtype tmp;
        tmp.str = st.str;
        return tmp;
    }
};

int main()
{
    strtype d = "NEWSPAPER";

}
```

Comment: Because temporaries cannot bind to mutable references. Your `operator=` overload must take a `const` reference as a parameter.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik `operator=()` involved in `strtype d = "NEWSPAPER";`

Comment: @A.Dimitrov Don't change the semantics of code posted in questions.

Comment: Once you have got this working with one of the answers below. Please take it to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ for a review. They will fill you in on a couple of best practices.

Answer (score 3):

For

> ```
> strtype d = "NEWSPAPER";
> ```

to work you would have to provide a constructor that takes a `char const*` as argument.

Also, use the initialization list of constructors to initialize member variables instead of assignments in the constructors body:

```
class strtype {
    string str;
public:
    strtype()
    : str{ "Test" }
    {}

    strtype(string ss)
    : str{ ss }
    {}

    strtype(char const *ss)
    : str{ ss }
    {}

    strtype& operator=(strtype const &st)  // *)
    {
        str = st.str;
        return *this;
    }
};
```

*) Assignment operators should in general take references to `const` and also return a reference to the object.

Comment: Sorry. Read too fast.

Answer (score 1):

First, your operator should take a const-reference as parameter:

```
strtype operator= (const strtype &st)
```

Second, the assignment operator expects a `strtype` and not a `const char*`. So just overload another operator for this:

```
strtype& operator= (const char* c) {
    str = c;
    return *this;
}
```

You also want to change the contents of your first operator like that:

```
strtype& operator= (const strtype &st) {
        str = st.str;
        return *this;
    }
```

This is important, so when using the assignment operator to assign a new value to a strtype object, you want it to change the values and not create a new one. This would not have an effect. The return value is just there in case you chain multiple assignments, so it can use the result of one assignment to put into the next one.